# How to insert data when registering trigger in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: triggers, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am trying to manage trigger in Apache IoTDB and I have a question. How can I directly insert data in time series when registering trigger in Apache IoTDB? Or is it only possible to use `session` to establish a connection to insert data in IoTDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Apache IoTDB，it is recommended to stop writing when registering triggers. When registering a trigger, there will be an intermediate state in which some nodes in the cluster have registered the trigger, and some nodes have not yet registered successfully. Therefore, performing writing is not recommended to avoid write requests on some nodes being listened to by triggers and not being listened to on some nodes.